A Zariski's Main Theorem for affine morphisms
Let $f: X\to Y$ be a birational affine surjective morphism with geometrically connected fibers between smooth $\mathbf{C}$-varieties.
Question: Is $f$ an isomorphism?
If $f$ is proper, then $f$ is finite and the result follows from Zariski's Main Theorem. Is this still true without the properness assumption?

Just to clarify, are you assuming the morphism is surjective, I.e., do you consider the empty set to be disconnected?  There are plenty of non-surjective counterexamples.

@JasonStarr Yes, $f$ is surjective (otherwise open immersions are counterexamples)

Then that is true by $S2$ extension: the maximal open subset over which the morphism is an isomorphism has codimension $\geq 2$ complement in the target, so the pullback map on global sections of the structure sheaf is an isomorphism.
